# Page change becomes slow when time goes by in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using AngularJS 1.5.6 in a single page application. I've two controllers `DashboardController` and `MainController`. `DashboardController` has a link to move to `MainController` and vice-versa. After jumping between these pages 5 times the transition becoming very slow. Strangely all the other click handlers and interactions are working fine. Only the route change time increases when time passes. I'm also using AngularJS UI router.

If it's a memory leak issue then everything should become slow right? In this case only the route change is getting slower. How can I debug this issue? any clue??

Comment: I would say you should add logging to locationChangeStart, locationChangeSuccess. Also take look into resolve's if any.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov You are right. There is a nav bar directive that does some ajax calls and does magic routing. Looks like there are some resolves that delaying the route transition.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Can you post your reply as answer?